# ModalPopupExtender and Progress GIF not hitting Button_Click on Post-Back

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm trying to use a ModalPopupExtender and an animated gif to create a type of "processing..." window.

The page this is on can take a while to process the requests...there's no way to speed it up at the current time. Eventually, I could switch it to a job that runs on the DB behind the scenes and emails them when done..but for now I just need to show a popup modal processing window.

The modalpopup works and displays the panel I've attached to it...the problem is that the button postback never fires. This is not an AJAX call but a full postback. I've done similar things on other pages by turning a panel on using JavaScript but on this page I want to use a modal panel so they can't mess with any of the controls.

Is this possible?

Here's my code:

Server-side button handler:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'do stuff here
Dim str As String = ""
End Sub
```

Client-side:

```
...
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
...
<asp:Panel ID="pnlProgress" runat="server" style="display:none">
<div class="borderPanel">Hello!!</div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="pnlProgress" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG" BehaviorID="modalpopup" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
...
```

So when I click Button1, the modal displays but the postback never hits the server-side method.
Any ideas? (BTW, the controls are generically named because this is just a test.)

Thanks, George

---

Here's my new code...
JS code in HEAD:

```
function ShowPopup() {
  $find('modalpopup').show();
  return true;
}
```

Button, Panel MPE code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="login" OnClientClick="ShowPopup();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="programmaticModalPopup" BehaviorID="modalpopup" TargetControlID="loginButton" PopupControlID="programmaticPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="True" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowScroll"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="ModalPopupBG" ID="programmaticPopup" Style="background-color: #FFFFCC; display: none; height: 25px; width: 85px; padding: 10px">
    <div id='messagediv' style="text-align: center">
    Loading...</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Server-Side Code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'do stuff here
    Dim str As String = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add click event (OnClick="Button1_Click") in button tag.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Your problem is that the ModalPopup is showing Client side.

You need do trigger a postback to the server.

add a dummy target for the ModalPopup

```
< asp:Button runat="server" ID="HiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" style="display:none" />
```

set TargetControlID="HiddenTargetControlForModalPopup"

call ModalPopupExtender1.show() inside the Button1_Click event.

Button1 will now trigger a serverside event.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .ModalPopupBG
        {
            background-color: #666699;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        .HellowWorldPopup
        {
            min-width: 200px;
            min-height: 150px;
            background: white;
        }
        .hide
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="hide" />
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="Button2" PopupControlID="Panel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="messagediv"
            Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" Style="display: none" runat="server">
            <div id='messagediv' style="text-align: center"  class="HellowWorldPopup">
                Loading...

            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page Behind Code

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show()

    End Sub
```

You can hide ModalPopup using

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Hide() ;
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: OK, I did that but it's still not firing. Just to summarize: 1. popup panel displays properly, 2) server-side still isn't firing.

Comment: you have set TargetControlID="Button1" in modelpopup you need to change the button id if you want to server side event from it. add a dummy target for the ModalPopup.

Comment: Wait...explain that again? I thought the TargetControlID had to point to the control that is supposed to activate the MPE?

Comment: I do have the OnClick event in my button, I also have the method on the server-side with the Handles Button1.Click. I don't understand what you mean...I have to add a dummy control to my page for the PME? Also, if the server-side method calls the .Show method then it won't show until the page is reloaded right? I want the panel to show WHILE the server-side code is running...

Comment: please show me your updated code.You can edit your question and post updated code there. So i can see what is actual problem.

Comment: I did manage to update my post...see above for the latest version of the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into an UpdateProgress control?  Is there a particular reason you want to do the ModalPopup?

Edited:
Have you tried using the Button's `OnClientClick` property?  That would enable you to display the modal popup via JavaScript, then follow onto the server side and run your time-consuming operation.

Make sure to `return true;` from your javascript method, so that the full PostBack will fire down to the server.

Comment: I don't want people clicking on other controls while waiting.

Comment: Updated with another option to try.